# In Many to Many relationship, How do you prevent round trips? - Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

This is an example of my data model:

```
public class House : Record
{
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Street> Streets { get; set; } 
}

public class Street
{
    public int StreetId { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<House> HouseUnit { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<House> HouseUnitParallel { get; set; } 
}
```

I would like to obtain just StreetId and StreetName for every house record from streets (excluding HouseUnit and HouseUnitParallel).

```
var entities = context.Houses.Include(r => r.Streets.Select(s => new 
{
     StreetId = s.StreetId, 
     StreetName = s.StreetName
}));
```

This code throws the following exception:

```
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. 
Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator 
for collection navigation properties.
```

For every House Record, I would like to exclude the HouseUnit and HouseUnitParallel collections inside of my street property (because it piggybacks a bunch of houses to my House record).

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I think you want this:

```
var entities = context.Houses
                      .Include(r => r.Streets)
                      .SelectMany(h => h.Streets
                                        .Select(s => new 
                                        {
                                            StreetId = s.StreetId, 
                                            StreetName = s.StreetName
                                        }));
```

As long as you don't have lazy loading disabled elsewhere, your virtual ICollections won't be eager loaded unless Include'd; HouseUnit and HouseUnitParallel should be left out.

**EDIT:**

Looking at your code causing the exception again, it could be that you're just over-thinking it: to exclude HouseUnit and HouseUnitParallel, you simply don't `Include` them:

```
var entities = context.Houses.Include(r => r.Streets);
```

This will – again, assuming you don't have lazy loading disabled elsewhere – include `Streets` in the set of `House`s returned, but not the relations on `Street`; contrast this with

```
var entities = context.Houses
                      .Include(r => r.Streets.Select(s => s.HouseUnits))
                      .Include(r => r.Streets.Select(s => s.HouseUnitParallel));
```

which *will* include all the relations.

If you attempt the former, and you are still getting all relations, you should look to see if Lazy Loading has been disabled (i.e., `LazyLoadingEnabled = false`) elsewhere in your project. Even if it has, you should be able to enable it just for this `context` scope by calling `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true` just before the LINQ query.

Comment: Bu then you would get only streets back as anonymous type ignoring all the house properties which defeats the purpose of the join.

Comment: @eugenekgn - the OP appeared to only want the properties StreetId and StreetName (how do I know? he said "I would like to obtain just StreetId and StreetName" ... also, his attempted solution returned only those properties in the `Select`). He also appeared content with an anonymous type (again, because his solution returned an anonymous type in the `Select`).

Comment: It could be that I misinterpreted what OP was trying to do - I'll edit my answer.